# Buttons Added to FlowLayoutPanel pile up on top of each other

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VS 2012 (vb.net) and I have a form with a flowLayoutPanel which is meant to contain an unknown number of buttons. To make it simple, basically, when the form Loads I fetch items from a table based one some criteria and then a use a For...Next block to add a button for each item to the flowLayoutPanel. So if I find 5 items I add 5 buttons all named differently but the problem is that they seem to pile up on each other instead of lining up nicely. When I use a button to add the items one after the other it works fine but when I use the For...Next block it does not work. I have tried refreshing the flowLayoutPanel after adding each button, I have tried to set the location of each new button relative to the location of the previous button but it still does to work.
I have researched this for over a week now and there is a ton of stuff out there but nothing specifically deals with this.

Thanks for your help.

This is the relevant part of my code:

`Try
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Open()
            End If

```
        sql = "SELECT ItemCode, Description, NormalPrice FROM items WHERE items.Class = 'ICE CREAM'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        'fill dataset
        da.Fill(ds, "items")
        rowscount = ds.Tables("items").Rows.Count

        If rowscount > 0 Then 'there are records so go ahead
            Dim ID As Integer
            Dim desc As String
            Dim newbutton As New Button
            Dim newCode As New TextBox

            For i As Integer = 0 To rowscount - 1
                ID = ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("ItemCode")
                desc = ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("Description")

                newCode.Name = "mnuCode" & i
                newCode.Text = ID
                newCode.Visible = False
                Me.Controls.Add(newCode)

                newbutton.Name = "mnuButton" & i
                newbutton.Text = desc
                newbutton.Size = New Size(150, 100)
                newbutton.BackColor = Color.Orange
                newbutton.ForeColor = Color.White
                newbutton.Font = New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold)
                newbutton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                newbutton.Text = Regex.Unescape(desc)

                newbutton.Top = (150 + (i * 100))
                fPanel.Refresh()

                AddHandler newbutton.Click, AddressOf ButtonClicked
                fPanel.Controls.Add(newbutton)
            Next
        End If
        ds.Reset()
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException

    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try`
```

Comment: It might be easier for someone to help you if you posted some of your code that shows what you've done.

Comment: It is likely due to you setting the `Top` when you should leave that alone and let the `FLP` do it's job. The `newCode` and `newbutton` variables should be declared in the loop not outside it. There is no reason to call `fPanel.Refresh` unless it does not update when adding - cause it should.

Comment: Like magic it worked. I moved the variable declarations to within the loop as you said and that was it. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating multiple buttons.  You just keep changing the properties on the same button over and over again.  Since `Button` is a *[reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)*, you need to call `New` each time you need a new object instance

For instance, instead of this:

```
Dim newbutton As New Button
For i As Integer = 0 To rowscount - 1
    ' ...
    fPanel.Controls.Add(newbutton)
Next
```

Do this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To rowscount - 1
    Dim newbutton As New Button
    ' ...
    fPanel.Controls.Add(newbutton)
Next
```

Or:

```
Dim newbutton As Button = Nothing
For i As Integer = 0 To rowscount - 1
    newbutton = New Button
    ' ...
    fPanel.Controls.Add(newbutton)
Next
```